# How to setup android navigation on jetpack compose using hilt with view models responsible for navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

I am getting this error when trying to navigate to another screen from the view model,

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property _navController has not been initialized
```

This is my activity code,

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var navigator: Navigator

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AssessmentAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                    .padding(vertical = 10.dp, horizontal = 10.dp), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    AssessmentApp(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 40.dp))
                    NavigationGraph(navigator)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my navigation module,

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesNavigation() = Navigator()
}
```

This is my navigation class,

```
@ActivityRetainedScoped
class Navigator {
    private lateinit var _navController: NavHostController

    fun navigate(destination: NavigationDestination) {
        _navController.navigate(destination.route)
    }

    fun setController(controller: NavHostController) {
        _navController = controller
    }
}
```

this is the navigation graph where I am remembering the navController,

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(
    navigator: Navigator
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    navigator.setController(navController)
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.CLIENTS_ROUTE ) {
        composable(Routes.CLIENTS_ROUTE) {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ClientViewModel>()
            ClientScreen(viewModel = viewModel)
        }
        composable(Routes.ASSESSMENT_OPTIONS_ROUTE, arguments = listOf(navArgument(RouteArgs.CLIENT_ID) {type = NavType.StringType})) { backStackEntry ->
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ClientViewModel>()
            ClientAssessmentOptionScreen(viewModel = viewModel)
        }
}
```

finally, this is one of view models trying to navigate to different screen,

```
@HiltViewModel
class ClientViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: IClientRepository,
    private val navigator: Navigator,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
    
    // Some code here //

    fun onEvent(event: ClientEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when(event) {
                is ClientEvent.OnClientClicked -> {
                    event.client.clientName?.let {
                        navigator.navigate(
                            NavigationDestination(Routes.generateAssessmentOptionsRoute(clientId = it))
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? and is the approach to make view models handle navigation the right one for jetpack compose applications?

Comment: what about removing `lateinit` and handle the fact that `_navController` can be nullable inside the `Navigator` class?

Comment: Okay so I have also tried something like this, `_navController?.navigate(destination.route)` but `_navController` is always `null` and it does not perform any navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering it here in case someone else also stumbles upon this. I have modified my navigator class and added a `shared flow`. Which would be used sort of as an event emitter. Whenever we would want to navigate to another screen we can use the `navigate` method which would emit the route destination.

```
@Singleton
class Navigator {
    private val _sharedFlow =
        MutableSharedFlow<NavigationDestination>(extraBufferCapacity = 1)
    val sharedFlow = _sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()

    fun navigate(destination: NavigationDestination) {
        _sharedFlow.tryEmit(destination)
    } 
}
```

Now in the `NavigationGraph`, I have remembered the `NavController` and have also added a `launchedEffect` coroutine, which would be listening to the navigate events from the flow. For each flow event, we will trigger the `NavController` to navigate to that emitted destination.

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    navigator: Navigator
) {
    LaunchedEffect("navigation") {
        navigator.sharedFlow.onEach {
            navController.navigate(it.route)
        }.launchIn(this)
    }

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.CLIENTS_ROUTE ) {
    // some code here... //
    }
}
```

Comment: if lets say I have 2 navController for 2 different navHost, how to scope each of them? so if the second navHost is binded, also the navController binded to the particular navhost